# How to use seaparate controllers in folder modules on codeigniter HMVC?

Tags: codeigniter, hmvc

CI HMVC tree defaults:

```
modules/
..login/controllers/Login.php
..home/controllers/Home.php
```

i want to create this tree

```
modules/
..frontend/login/controllers/Login.php
..frontend/home/controllers/Home.php
..backend/table/controllers/Table.php
..backend/password/controllers/Password.php
```

But when i try to call `http://domain/frontend/login` : this give me 401 error result.

How to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the way to do this is

```
modules/
..frontend/controllers/login/Login.php
..frontend/controllers/home/Home.php
..backend/controllers/table/Table.php
..backend/controllers/password/Password.php
```

but be aware - if you want to access to login you need to call the folder and the controller even if they have the same name e.g. `http://ci.dev/backend/login/login/`